# How many seven digit numbers with distinct digits contain a $3$ but not a $6$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many $7$-digit numbers with no repeated digits contain a $3$ but not a $6$? The number does not start with zero.

$$7 \cdot P(8,6) = 7 \cdot 20160 = 141120$$
because $3$ can be in $7$ positions, and then $6$ positions left and $8$ digits to place because $3$ already in a position, $6$ cannot be used, and $0$ can be used now.

Is this correct thinking? Thank you.

edit: If $3$ is in the first position, then $P(8,6)$ because now zero can be any position. If $3$ not in first position, then $0$ have $5$ position to choose from. This mean $P(8,5) \cdot 6$ because $3$ can be in $6$ other positions after the first position.

$P(8,6) + (P(8,5) \cdot 6)$ is the answer I think.

Comment: You still have to deal with the case of $0$ in the first digit, and exclude those.

Comment: That's still wrong, because $0$ might not be in the number. Start with your original answer, then *subtract* the cases where you put $0$ in the first digit.

Comment: ($7 * P(8,6)$) - $P(8,6)$ because cases where 0 is first position is only one case. then eight digits left for six position to chose from.

Comment: Doing it this way, you would get $7\cdot P(8,6)-6\cdot P(7,5)$, since if 0 is the first digit, then there are 6 choices for placing the 3 and $P(7,5)$ ways to fill the remaining 5 places.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a $3$ in the millions place, then the number of ways we can fill the remaining six positions with distinct digits is $P(8, 6)$ since we can use any digit other than $3$ or $6$.

If the $3$ is not in the millions place, then there are six ways to place the $3$ in the remaining six positions.  There are seven ways to choose the digit in the millions place since we cannot use $0$, $3$, or $6$.  The number of ways of filling the remaining five positions with distinct digits is $P(7, 5)$ since we cannot use $3$, $6$, or the digit in the millions place.

Hence, the number of seven digit positive integers with no repeated digits that contain a $3$ but not a $6$ is $P(8, 6) + 6 \cdot 7 \cdot P(7, 5)$.

The mistake you made was not taking into account the fact that you cannot use zero as the first digit.